# looping through controls in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, controls

I have several labels on my UIView that I want to change the properties on. What I would like to do is iterate through them setting/getting there values.  If you are familiar with C# then it's the FindControl function I am trying to emulate.

In essence the question is how to get all the controls on a UIView so I can manipulate them.

Any help greatly appreicated.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subviews property of a UIView gives you an NSArray holding all subviews.